# how to print "&" character in xslt?

Tags: xslt

I'm working with XSLT 1.0 and I would liked to print "&" (ampersand) character, as it is special character in xslt, it gives error. So please suggest the option.
As we use `&lt;` to print "<" character.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ampersand+xslt)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use encoded version of & sign

```
&amp;
```

Answer (score 1):

`&amp;` or `($amp;` if `$lt;` works) will solve.